# ‘struct user_regs_struct’ has no member named ‘rsi’ in sys/user.h

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am installing a python software named 'lorun' on centos8.

> uname -a : Linux ecs-kc1-large-2-linux-20200801141048 4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.aarch64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 4 23:44:08 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

When I'm compiling a .h file named 'access.h',some error has occurred:

```
In file included from lorun/cext/access.c:19:
lorun/cext/access.c: In function ‘checkAccess’:
lorun/cext/access.h:30:33: error: ‘struct user_regs_struct’ has no member named ‘orig_rax’
     #define REG_SYS_CALL(x) ((x)->orig_rax)
                                 ^~
lorun/cext/access.c:46:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘REG_SYS_CALL’
     if (!runobj->inttable[REG_SYS_CALL(regs)])
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
lorun/cext/access.h:30:33: error: ‘struct user_regs_struct’ has no member named ‘orig_rax’
     #define REG_SYS_CALL(x) ((x)->orig_rax)
                                 ^~
lorun/cext/access.c:49:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘REG_SYS_CALL’
     switch (REG_SYS_CALL(regs)) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
lorun/cext/access.c:50:14: error: ‘SYS_open’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SYS_openat’?
         case SYS_open: {
              ^~~~~~~~
              SYS_openat
lorun/cext/access.c:50:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from lorun/cext/access.c:19:
lorun/cext/access.h:31:30: error: ‘struct user_regs_struct’ has no member named ‘rdi’
     #define REG_ARG_1(x) ((x)->rdi)
                              ^~
lorun/cext/access.c:56:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘REG_ARG_1’
                     REG_ARG_1(regs) + i * sizeof(long), NULL);
                     ^~~~~~~~~
lorun/cext/access.c:59:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
                 for (j = 0; j < sizeof(long); j++) {
                               ^
In file included from lorun/cext/access.c:19:
lorun/cext/access.h:32:30: error: ‘struct user_regs_struct’ has no member named ‘rsi’
     #define REG_ARG_2(x) ((x)->rsi)
                              ^~
lorun/cext/access.c:68:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘REG_ARG_2’
                     REG_ARG_2(regs))) {
                     ^~~~~~~~~
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It says that there is no fields named `rdi` in `struct user_regs_struct`. I went to watch the `/usr/include/sys/user.h`,and it dose not has that field.

[user.h of centos8][1]

but i went to watch the same file in centos 7 ,it has all the fields of the user.
[user.h of centos7][2]

now i want to use the fields in centos7 ,but using centos8 .what should i do ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgYNn.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3on2Y.png

Answer (score 1):

Your uname suggests that you’re running on AArch64, i.e. 64-bit ARM. rdi, rsi, orig_rax and the like are registers on 64-bit Intel processors, indicating that the code you’re working with has Intel-specific code that hasn’t been ported to ARM.

Unfortunately, unless you know how to port that code, you probably will not be able to get this to work. I would suggest filing a bug report with the project and seeing if the maintainers or developers will be willing to make the appropriate changes.

EDIT: given that this appears to be an Amazon AWS box, you also have the option of just starting over with an Intel (x86_64) machine, assuming that your other dependencies will work there.

Comment: thank you very much . i think i should change my platform to x86_64.

Comment: Yes, also an option.